# Regex find specific string only between two other specific strings

Tags: php, html, css, regex

Basically, I need to replace the css class alert in about 3000 documents because it breaks bootstrap css.  I can find the entire css class by searching `(?<=class=")(.*)(?=")`, but I can't just find the alert class by using `(?<=class=".*)(alert)(?=.*")` or anything like that.

Basically, given a set of data:

```
<div class=" big alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class="alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" big solid">Alert alert</div>
```

I only want to find the text alert inside the class attribute.

I have a feeling if there is a working solution for this it will involve optional wildcards in the look ahead/behind.  Something like:

```
(?<=class="(.)?)(.*)(?=(.)?")
```

Comment: `because it breaks bootstrap css` why not alter bootstrap css? And if you can't/don't want to, you should parse those pages using a proper DOM parser, do not use a regex.

Comment: I'm not talking about anything in a web browser or using javascript.  I'm talking about documents in a file system in FreeBSD.

Comment: How about `(?<=class=")(.*alert.*)(?=")`

Comment: @MElliott  That's the first thing I tried, it finds all classes in the class attribute.  I need the wildcards to be part of the look ahead/behind, I would think.

Comment: @user1119648 Nor am I, I'm talking about PHP.

Comment: Do a string replace of "alert" on the matched capture groups.

Comment: If you really feel you need to use a regex for this, try looking at the + modifier on the string alert, i.e. `[alert]+` - it may be an interpretation problem rather than anything else?

Comment: I'm not sure I know any way to replace possibly tens of thousands of appearances of a string in many thousands of files other than a regex.

Comment: @RainFromHeaven Because we're integrating two different code bases, and going forward, I don't want the confusion of us having to use our special bootstrap class names vs standard bootstrap class names.

Comment: @user1119648 Could there be several `alert` in one class attribute ?

Comment: Here is a [simple fiddle](http://regex101.com/r/oS3gJ4). For a more robust solution try [this](http://regex101.com/r/kH5oV3).

Comment: Ah as for the lookbehinds: in php (well in almost every language) the lookbehind needs to be of **fixed length**. Which means `(?<=a.*?)b` doesn't work. The "workaround" is to use the `\K` escape sequence `a.*?\Kb`. The regex engine will "forget" what it matched. Try to play with it on regex101.com. On a side note, just use an html parser. It's reliable and saves you a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

You can try expression like this:

```
(?<=class\s?=\s?")(.*?)alert(.*?)(?=")
```

and replacement placeholder then will be like

```
$1$2
```

resulting in

```
<div class=" big  solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" big solid">Alert alert</div>
```

Comment: PHP preg `5.3.6–5.3.18` and `5.4.9–5.4.13` does not support variable repetition inside lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for any tag e.g. `div`, `span` and `p`:

```
(<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b[^>]*\bclass\s*=\s*"(?:|[^"]+))\balert\b((?:|[^"]+)")
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Regular expression for just `div` tags:

```
(<div\b[^>]*\bclass\s*=\s*"(?:|[^"]+))\balert\b((?:|[^"]+)")
```

As a replacement choose one of the following:

Replace `alert` with `alternative-alert-class-name`:

```
$1alternative-alert-class-name$2
```

Or replace `alert` with nothing:

```
$1$2
```

PHP code (note the use of case insensitivity):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(<[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b[^>]*\bclass\s*=\s*"(?:|[^"]+))\balert\b((?:|[^"]+)")/imx', '$1alternative-alert-class-name$2', $subject);
```

Example input:

```
<div class="alert">Alert alert</div>
<div class="alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class = "alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" big alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class = " big alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div something="xx" class = " big alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<span enabled something="xx" class = " big alert solid">Alert alert</span>
<div class=" big solid">Alert alert</div>
```

Example output:

```
<div class="alternative-alert-class-name">Alert alert</div>
<div class="alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class = "alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" big alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class = " big alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</div>
<div something="xx" class = " big alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</div>
<span enabled something="xx" class = " big alternative-alert-class-name solid">Alert alert</span>
<div class=" big solid">Alert alert</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$data = <<<EOD
<div class=" big alert solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class = "other-alert-class solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=" big solid">Alert alert</div>
<div class=' big alert solid'>Alert alert</div>
<div class  =  alert>Alert alert</div>
EOD;

$pattern = '~\sclass\s*=\s*(?>["\'](?>[^"\'a]++|(?<=\B|-)a|a(?!lert\b[^-]))*)?\Kalert\b~';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, 'otherclass', $data);
```